# JQuery slide effect and floating elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, slide, side-effects

I would like to do something like you can see on this image:
[image: Example]

That is: A slidable div and side div following the slidable div. I use this code:

```html
<div id="container">
<div id="side" style="float:right;" onclick="$('#slidable').toggle('slide');">…</div>
<div id="slidable" style="float:right;">…</div>
</div>
```

My issue is that the side div only starts to move when the slidable div has finished to slide. How can I do to make both divs animated at the same time ?

You can see the full example here : http://jsfiddle.net/azmeuk/QgD5Y/7/

Comment: there's no `slide` option in `.toggle()`

Comment: Do you not want slideToggle() - http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/

Comment: No sliding works great. Please look at the example http://jsfiddle.net/azmeuk/QgD5Y/7/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at this code

**HTML**

```
   <div id="container">
        <div id="slidable"class="hide">Foobar</div>
        <div id="side">+</div>
    </div>
```

I have added a `class` '**hide'** to `div` with **id="slidable"** just to hide it when the page loads. If you don't want it, you may remove.

**CSS** (Only change is I have added `hide` class)

```
#side{
    float:right;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:#BBB;
}

.hide{
    display:none;
}

#slidable{
    float:right;
    height:50px;
    background:#888;
    width:200px;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#side" ).click(function() {
     $('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });
  })
```

[**JSFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/shijukbabu/QgD5Y/8/)

Answer (score 3):

Here try this instead:

```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#side" ).click(function() {
      $( "#slidable" ).animate({width: 'toggle'});
      });
  });
```

Comment: This site help alot: http://www.learningjquery.com/2009/02/slide-elements-in-different-directions

Answer (score 1):

using jquery UI for this kind of matter is an overkill for me...

 well, we're here already so, what I could suggest is for you to use `toggleClass()` instead...

like this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/YE9pu/)

add some css

```
#slidable.open {
    margin-right: -200px
}
```

and change your jQuery codes to

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#side" ).click(function() {
      $( "#slidable" ).toggleClass( "open", 500 );
      });
  });
```